# C# : error CS0123: No overload for 'NewConnectionHandler' matches delegate 'Action<NewConnectionEventArgs>'

Tags: c#

i have this code :

```
namespace Hazel
{
    public struct NewConnectionEventArgs
    {
        
        public readonly MessageReader HandshakeData;

        
        public readonly Connection Connection;

        public NewConnectionEventArgs(MessageReader handshakeData, Connection connection)
        {
            this.HandshakeData = handshakeData;
            this.Connection = connection;
        }
    }
}




public class UdpConnectionListener : NetworkConnectionListener
{
    ....
}

namespace Hazel
{
   
    public abstract class ConnectionListener : IDisposable
    {
        public event Action<NewConnectionEventArgs> NewConnection;           
        public abstract void Start();
    }
}
```

This i try to call it with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UdpConnectionListener listener = new UdpConnectionListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4296));
    listener.NewConnection += NewConnectionHandler;
}

private static void NewConnectionHandler(object sender, NewConnectionEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New connection from " + args.Connection.EndPoint.ToString());
}
```

but i keep getting :

```
error CS0123: No overload for 'NewConnectionHandler' matches delegate 'Action<NewConnectionEventArgs>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static void NewConnectionHandler(object sender, NewConnectionEventArgs args)
```

should change to

```
private static void NewConnectionHandler(NewConnectionEventArgs args)
```

the event type is Action no object sender.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what is *delegate*.

*A delegate* is a like a function pointer in C and C++, except that it can contain multiple functions. It can also return a value, in case of multiple functions the last function decides about the return value.

A delegate is a type, just like classes, structs and enums.

Example:

```cs
public delegate void Foo(int i); // Can be outside of class

public class C
{
    public static void F(int i)
    {
    }
}

Foo foo = null;
foo += C.F; // Add C.F to foo
foo += C.F; // Add C.F to foo, second time
foo += delegate (int i) {}; // Add an anonymous function to foo
foo += (i) => {}; // Add an anonymous function to foo

foo(); // Call all functions in foo()
```

We can save time in case we want to create a delegate and immediately assign it a function:

```cs
MyDelegate delegate = new MyDelegate(MyFunction);
// Is the same as
MyDelegate delegate = MyFunction;
```

`System.Action` and `System.Func` are just handful collection of generic delegates that are predefined in .NET since .NET 2 to help us. Their definition is as follows:

```cs
public delegate void Action();
public delegate void Action<T1>(T1 t1);
public delegate void Action<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2);
// ...and so until T17
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();
public delegate TResult Action<T1, TResult>(T1 t1);
public delegate TResult Action<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 t1, T2 t2);
// ...and so until T17
```

*An event* is just a delegate, with one important difference: you can add and remove methods from event, but you can reassign to all. Why? take the previous example:

```cs
public delegate void Foo(int i); // Can be outside of class

public class C
{
    public static void F(int i)
    {
    }
}

Foo foo = null;
foo += C.F;
foo += C.F;
foo += delegate (int i) {};
foo = (i) => {}; // Oops, `=` instead of `+=`

foo(); // Call all functions in foo() - but they're just the last, is it overwritten the previous!
```

This is useful usually, but can lead to mistakes with events. Using C# events we can make that a compile error:

```cs
public delegate void Foo(int i); // Can be outside of class

public class C
{
    public static event Foo E; // Cannot be outside class - events are not types, but instance of delegates
    public static void F(int i)
    {
    }
}

C.E += C.F;
C.E += C.F;
C.E += delegate (int i) {};
C.E = (i) => {}; // Compile error!

foo(); // Call all functions in foo();
```

`System.EventHandler` and `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>` are helpful delegates for events:

```cs
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

This is the usual pattern for events in .NET (sending the sender and a subclass of `System.EventArgs`), although no-one forces that.

From the above explanation, you can understand what's wrong with your code. Your code defines an event with `System.Action<T1>`, then you don't have `sender`:

```cs
public event Action<NewConnectionEventArgs> NewConnection;
```

What you really want is `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>`:

```cs
public event EventHandler<NewConnectionEventArgs> NewConnection;
```

Comment: thanks for the info , i was thinking the sender is a hidden arg object like "this" in C++